# how to run Oracle .sql file using java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to run an Oracle script using java code how can I do that ?

My SQL files has many statements with IF and WHEN and also create and grant statements
tried using ScriptWriter and it's not working the same sql file i am able to in the sql developer

Comment: Why does it need to be executed with java and not directly with sqlplus?  Why are you using a complicated script to create tables, which should be done one time, as part of the system design?

Comment: Does oracle have any command line tools? If so, you could run it with `ProcessBuilder` and send it the script. And yes, I agree with @EdStevens that this is not really something for an application layer

Comment: _"Does oracle have any command line tools?"_  Um . . . like, say, sqlplus?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method (in Java) is to assume that the SQL script was written in a reasonably readable manner and that there is either 1 statement-per-line or that statements are split over multiple lines and you will not have the case where there are multiple statements on a single line.

The majority of cases can be handled by:

Read the next line and trim any leading white-space:

- If it starts with `SET` or `COLUMN` then you have a SQL/Plus directive which will (typically) consist of a single line; that line is your statement.
- If it starts with `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE PACKAGE`, `DECLARE` or `BEGIN` (and a following white-space character) then you will have a PL/SQL block that will be terminated with a `/` on a separate line and you can read lines until you have found it and that is your complete statement.
- If it starts with `--` then it is a comment and you can skip the rest of the line and prepend it to the next statement (since comments are part of the next statement).
- If it starts with `/*` then it is an inline comment and you can read until the next `*/` and then repeat by processing the rest of the line (the comment will be prepended to the next statement).
- Otherwise, read until the next `;` that is at the end of a line (or followed by a comment) (or `/` on a separate line) and that is your complete statement.

Then repeat, reading the next line.

Once you have each statement then execute them one-after-another.

This is not guaranteed to work on 100% of cases (i.e. if you have multi-line string literals which happen to have a `;` at then end of a line within the literal). You should review the output to see if there are any additional cases that need to be handled but for relatively simple scripts it should work.

If you have developers that like writing (less readable) scripts with multiple statements on the same line then you may need to implement a parser.

> How do you handle IF statements?

`IF` is a PL/SQL statement and will only be found within a PL/SQL block that starts with `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE PACKAGE`, `DECLARE` or `BEGIN` and terminates with a `/` on a separate line (see the second bullet point above). It is not a valid statement on its own so you should not have to handle it.

Similarly, `WHEN` is part of another statement/expression such as a `CASE` expression or an `EXIT` statement and will be within an SQL statement or a PL/SQL block; you do not need any additional handling as it will be covered by one of the options above.

---

Even simpler though, is to run the SQL file from the command line using SQL/plus.

Comment: How do you handle IF statements?

Comment: @saka1029 `IF` is a PL/SQL statement and will only be found within a PL/SQL block that starts with `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE PACKAGE`, `DECLARE` or `BEGIN` and terminates with a `/` on a separate line (see the second bullet point of the answer). It is not a valid statement on its own so you should not have to handle it.